# How do I write to string buffer from C in ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

### The problem

I'm trying to use `ctypes` to use a C function in Python. The function `reverse` should write the reverse version of `stri` to `stro`.

rev.c:

```
#include <stddef.h>
/* length is the length of the string EXCLUDING the \0 terminator
*/
void reverse(char * stro, char * stri, size_t length)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<length; i++) stro[i]=stri[length-1-i];
    stro[length]='\0';
}
```

rev.py:

```
from ctypes import *

revlib = cdll.LoadLibrary("rev.so");
reverse = revlib.reverse
reverse.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p, c_size_t]

hello = "HelloWorld"
stri = create_string_buffer(hello)
stro = create_string_buffer(b'\000' * (len(hello)+1))

reverse(stro, stri, len(stri))

print(repr(stri.value))
print(repr(stro.value))
```

I compiled the c file with `gcc -o rev.so -shared -fPIC rev.c`, invoked `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` and then I tried the above python script. This is the output:

```
$ python rev.py 
'HelloWorld'
''
```

I expected the second line to be `'dlroWolleH'`. I avoided whitespaces just in case they could cause problems.

### What I have tried

I compiled the above c function with `gcc rev.c -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic` and it produced no warnings.

The function seems work when I use this main function:

```
int main() {
    char * str = "Hello, World";
    char o[100];
    reverse(o, str, strlen(str));
    puts(str);
    puts(o);
}
```

which yields this output:

```
$ gcc rev.c; ./a.out 
Hello, World
dlroW ,olleH
```

Just to try to successfully write to a buffer, I tried `sscanf` like this:

```
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
stri = create_string_buffer(100)
libc.sscanf("HelloWorld", "%s", stri)
print(repr(stri.value))
```

And this prints the expected result. But my function does not seem to be able to write to the buffer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Python string are immutable, which means they can't be changed. I suggest you modify your C function to return a value.

Comment: @martineau OP is writing to a ctypes string buffer, not Python strings

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I realize that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was actually quite simple. When you use `create_string_buffer`, it will add a null terminator to the string. This means that `len(stri)` will yield a result one bigger than `len(hello)`.

The solution was changing

```
reverse(stro, stri, len(stri))
```

to

```
reverse(stro, stri, len(stri)-1)
```

Here is a demonstration where I changed the input string to 'Hello, World!':

```
$ python rev.py
'Hello, World!'
'!dlroW ,olleH'
```